# Handling multiple tenants in ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: c#, .net-core, server

I have developed .NET Core Web Api application and, a few different customers using the same app with different configurations. (App loads a config json file, listens a few ports, connects to the database.)
For now, I'm using different servers for each customer to keep them separated.(Linode 1 Cpu, 1 GB Ram). It is very hard for me to publish updates, stopping starting service etc.

How do other devs do such things? Is there any way that I can merge the servers and manage it with single operation? OR what is the right way to do that?

Comment: It is basic web api with database connection. One extra is that server listens 2 extra ports for each client. (different ports for each one).

Comment: What you ask is called multi-tenancy. It's not trivial - you don't just have different configurations, you have different data, permissions, accounts. You need to prevent one tenant reading another's data.  The ASP.NET Core docs mention a few techniques mainly around Azure AD for authentication. Gunnar Peipman's [Multitenant web applications with ASP.NET Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/presentations/aspnet-core-multitenant/) describes multitenant ASP.NET Core applications at a high level, and the accompanying [Github Repo](https://github.com/gpeipman/AspNetCoreMultitenant) contains demo code

Comment: There are a *lot* of articles and blog posts about this, and no single best option. For example, you can identify tenants through a URL parameter, a header, or by first authenticating the caller and checking their account/claims. If. you use Azure AD or a similar authentication service, the service could include the tenant ID in the JWT token. To isolate database access you can use EF Core's global query filters to ensure each tenant sees their own data. How you store that is another story though - stored in different databases? Different tables in the same DB? Same table with a TenantID?

Comment: ASP.NET Core configuration can load settings from JSON, databases, external services. The tenant ID can become part of the setting key, eg a Section. Once you load all settings (again, there are a lot of options) you can read a single tenant's config by using the tenant-specific section

Comment: If you search learn.microsoft.com, you'll find several articles. Almost each middleware is affected by it and describes it in some way. For example, the DI docs contain a section on [Patterns for multi-tenancy in DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#recommended-patterns-for-multi-tenancy-in-di) eg [about data protection in multitenant apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/purpose-strings-multitenancy?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: The docs typically mention [Orchard Core](https://orchardcore.net/) as an example for multi-tenant configuration, DI *and* authentication and suggest [checking the source code](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchardcore) to see how this is done, although that particular architecture may be too much for a smaller application. On the other hand, it may be a good idea to build your web app using OrchardCore

Comment: One could write several books on multi-tenancy. There's no single way to do it. In some apps, different tenants have completely different content or in your case, APIs. In others, the same UI/API serves different data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple solution to handle this situation.
Host your web api on a single server and take a `CustomerName` or `CustomerCode` parameter in your web api, According to `CustomerName` or `CustomerCode` parameter route customer's api to appropriate method using switch case.

Comment: This doesn't work even for demo apps. What if another customer is added? Do you modify and redeploy the entire site, disrupting everyone else? Adding a tenant ID to the URL is not even 1% of the problem - the actual problem is handling different accounts, permissions, configurations and data for tenants.